# Display a "buffering" message - Netstream as3

Tags: flash, netstream, actionscript-3

how would I display a buffering animation whilst a netsream object was downloading video data? using Actionscript 3.0 in Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an event listener for [NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#NET_STATUS) to the NetStream object, then use [event.info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#info) to get the actual status, and react to either "NetStream.Buffer.Empty" or "NetStream.Buffer.Full".

There is a "how to use" example on the documentation page I linked to, which you can use to get started.